# Hapi js authentication schema implementation error / bug?

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I have authentication schema implementation like this

```
const schemeImplementation = (server, options) => {
  return {
    authenticate: (request, reply) => {
      authenticate(request)
      .then((credentials) => {
        return reply.continue({ credentials });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // not returning any response instead of timeout
        return reply(err);
      });
    }
  };
};
```

and in route handler

```
handler: (req, reply) => {
   throw new Error('This shouldn\'t lead to a timeout');
}
```

I am expecting it returns the error response correctly. Does anyone experience this before with Hapi?

> **notes: it only happens when synchronously throw an exception**
>   ref : https://hapijs.com/api#authentication-scheme

Answer (score 0):

IMO, the better way to resend the failure via Boom Plugin. I am using like this:-

```
const schemeImplementation = (server, options) => {
  return {
    authenticate: (request, reply) => {
      authenticate(request)
      .then((credentials) => {
        return reply.continue({ credentials });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        // this way it will directly return the error to client and would not go handler
        reply(Boom.badGateway(err));
      });
    }
  };
};
```